# How can I access enum in Class<T> in C#?

Tags: c#

I got an error `CS0305` with this piece of code. Is there a good way to do this ?

```cs
public class Filtre<T> : List<KeyValuePair<Filtre.Methode, object>>
{
    public enum Methode
    {
        Id,
        Keyword
    }
}
```

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0305](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0305)

Comment: thanks, already read it. Posted because i can't find the correct syntax

Comment: You might want to move the enum outside of the class. Note that it currently doesn't belong to the `Filtre` class. It belongs to the generic `Filtre<T>` class. So, in order to access it, you'd need to use `Filtre<Something>.Methode`. As I said, it might be a better idea to move it outside the class or to a different class (a `static` one, maybe).

Comment: @41686d6564 : yeah, it's working outside, and i'll do it that way if i can't find a way to keep the enum inside the class<T>

Comment: It makes no sense to embed a `public enum` inside a generic, it adds nothing as all variations of `Filtre<>` will share the _same definition_.  As mentioned above, move the definition _outside_

Comment: Why do you want to inherit from `List` anyway? [Favour composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to keep the enum inside `Filtre<T>`, then change the class signature as -

```cs
public class Filtre<T> : List<KeyValuePair<Filtre<T>.Methode, object>>
{
    public enum Methode
    {
        Id,
        Keyword
    }
}
```

But does that make any sense? Think about it, does the value of `T` by any means affect the enum `Methode`? No. Rather its adding unnecessary friction in code.

Also, you cannot declare the enum as anything less accessible than `public`, because then you will be making the base class `List<KeyValuePair<Filtre<T>.Methode, object>>` less accessible than `Filtre<T>`.

So, it will be better to declare the enum outside, and simplify the class signature -

```cs
public enum Methode
{
    Id,
    Keyword
}

public class Filtre<T> : List<KeyValuePair<Methode, object>>
{
    //
}
```